# Обработка 404 ошибки Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Столкнулся с проблемой - не могу отрендерить кастомную вьюшку для 404 ошибки Ларавел.

Есть код (в очень упрощенном виде)Ж

`if(!something) abort(404);`

Есть файл `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`, который я хочу показывать посетителям.

Согласно документации Ларавел (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#custom-http-error-pages) больше ничего не нужно, кастомная вьюшка для 404 ошибки должна выводиться без проблем.

**Тестируем.**
Вызываем 404 ошибку, и вместо `404.blade.php` получаем `Uncaught Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in...`

Не работает, иными словами.

**Ищем альтернативы.** В `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` правим метод `render` и делаем его вот таким

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception){

return response()->view('errors.404'); // здесь не важно какая ошибка, просто для проверки

return parent::render($request, $exception);

}
```

**Тестируем**. Получаем "Страница недоступна. Сайт site.com пока не может обработать этот запрос. HTTP ERROR 500"

Еще раз меняем метод `render` на

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception){

return response('Страницы не существует...');

return parent::render($request, $exception);

}
```

**Тестируем**. И, как ни странно, выводит `Страницы не существует...`

**Вопрос:** Почему не получается вывести в браузер `404.blade.php`?

**Код ошибки** если не править в app/Exceptions/Handler.php метод render (если править, код ошибки см. выше)

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message "Uncaught Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:992
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(46): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->abort(404, '', Array)
#1 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\app\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider.php(70): abort(404)
#2 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\app\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider.php(42): App\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider->getAntiLocaleURL()
#3 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Concerns\ManagesEvents.php(164): App\Providers\SiteViewServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#4 C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(344): Illuminate\View\Factory->Illuminate\View\Concerns\{closure}('composing: erro...', Array)
#5 C:\Do"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException in C:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\site.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:992
```

**Содержание файла 404.blade.php:**

`<h1>Это 404.blade.php</h1>`

**Все тесты проводились банальным вызовом abort(404)**

**UPDATE**

У меня есть мой сервис провайдер, вот его метод `boot`:

```
public function boot()
{

    abort(404);//если сгенерировать 404 ошибку отсюда, все прекрасно работает и 404.blade.php выводится без проблем

    View::composer(['*'], function ($view) {

    abort(404);//а вот если сгенерировать 404 ошибку отсюда, выводит ошибку, о которой писал выше

});


}
```

Получается, что вызов abort(404) из анонимной функции не позволяет поставить кастомную вьюшку на 404 ошибку???

Comment: Дайте полный текст ошибки где Вы тестировали 404. Так же покажите Вашу страницу 404.blade.php

Comment: Добавил информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш view composer распространяется в том числе и на страницу 404 ошибки (404.blade.php).
То есть во время рендеринга страницы 404 страницы вы повторно бросаете исключение NotFoundHttpException, что само по себе бессмысленно.

Если вам так уж надо вызывать abort() внутри view composer-а, не делайте это для страницы 404:

```
View::composer(['*'], function ($view) {
    if ($view->getName() !== "errors::404") {
        abort(404);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, бро! Действительно, ведь получается двойное исключение. 2 дня голову ломал)